# background-repeat is not working

Tags: css, background-image, repeat

I have one div :

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/pCVNE/1/) for my problem.

HTML :

```
 <div class="listinggitems">
 </div>
```

CSS :

```
.listinggitems
{
    min-height:280px;
    width:785px;    
    background: url(images/bgdoodle.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-xy;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:210px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

Upto `280px` height, background display but when div size automatically increase as data in it increase the background image doesn't increase.
I also tried `background-repeat:repeat-xy;` but it also display background upto `280px` after that it doesn't display it. when manually I increase height of `div` then background increase.
I have to load dynamic data into that `div` so I have to use `min-height`.

Any suggestion ???

Comment: why negative or down vote ?????

Comment: Anyone who have downvote visit http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-repeaty and add xy together and check..

Comment: w3schools?? Where is it?? I went to w3Fools - http://www.w3fools.com/ - (No negatives from me though)

Comment: it's not fools but it's schools.. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-repeaty

Comment: It is fools.. I also provided the link. Check this new link for instance. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120621/w3fools-alternatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your **HTML** ammend last 3 line's to :

```
            </div>
               <div class="clr"></div> 
            </div>
```

in CSS add :

```
.clr{clear:both}
```

**Why its happening??** You are setting the `child-divs` to float which means that the container div `(listinggitems)` cannot work out it's actual height. You need to clear the floated element which essentially lets the container know how large the image actualy is.

That's why u'll need to add an element with the style `clear: both;`

Comment: No Anyone from it not working due to min-height, upto min-height it display image but after it doesn't.

Comment: try these two options `background-size: cover;` OR `background-size: 100% 100%;`

Comment: No still it's not working. The problem is that I think I have have used so many div inside it, that's why I am getting problem.

Comment: if you can give a jsfiddle, that would be very helpful!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41707/discussion-between-mayank-and-user2659972-)

Answer (score 0):

Your `background-repeat` property declaration i.e `background-repeat:repeat-xy;` is incorrect.

Either use `background-repeat:repeat-x;` or `background-repeat:repeat-y;` or `background-repeat:repeat;` to repeat.

Check the below for a complete list of Background repeat attributes.

**[Link for CSS Background-repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat)**

Comment: No Anyone from it not working due to min-height, upto min-height it display image but after it doesn't.

Comment: so remove that, as your min-height in px is the same as the height of background image which you want to repeat, then it will not work. - @user2659972ღ

Comment: I am displaying dynamic data so as data increase the size of div should be increase, that's why I need min-height. are you want to remove min-height property ?

Comment: just keep it, but make sure that your dynamic data is coming in the same div, as creating multiple div for dynamic data and to put background repeat on the same div will not create repetitions. - @user2659972ღ

Comment: I have one other div inside it i.e. container and in that one main div  for one item and inside it div for image, div for name, div for price. so where I use that repeat ?

Comment: The "main div" - @user2659972ღ

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```
.listinggitems
{
    min-height:280px;
    width:785px;    
    background-image:url(images/bgdoodle.png);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:210px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hvqww/

Answer (score 0):

If you change to

```
background-repeat:repeat;
```

it's working fine, even if the height increases:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2xEYy/)